# Adding in extra vertical space with a new bullet point (using easylist)

Tags: spacing, notes, easylist

I'm using `easylist` to take notes and so far have really liked it. The only big problem I'm running into is it just doesn't quite look good sometimes because if you have multiple lines of text, then you make a new bullet point, the line spacing within a bullet point is the same spacing as the line spacing to the next bullet point.

I would like to make it so every time I create a new bullet point, there are a few extra pixels of vertical space.

Currently my easy list import looks like this

```
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\ListProperties(Hide=100, Hang=true, Progressive=8ex, Style*=$\bullet$ ,
Style2*=\textbf{--} ,Style3*=$\circ$ ,Style4*=\tiny$\blacksquare$ )
```

and so I would have something like

```
& This is a header note and blah blah blah blah blah until this note is 2 lines long
% Want a bigger vertical space here than occurred between the two lines in the first note
&& These are my sub notes
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add space between items of different levels add `Space=Npx` to your ListProperties. If you want to add space between items of identical levels add `Space*=Npx` to your ListProperties.

Note: N can be also negative, which is especially useful if you want them to be within a line space or narrower.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.